# What does the status code of the perl interpreter mean?

Tags: java, perl, exec, exit-code

I'm trying to execute a copy of the Perl interpreter using Java's Runtime.exec(). However, it returned error code `9`. After running the file a few times, the `perl` interpreter mysteriously started to return code 253 with no changes in my command at all.

What does code `253` / code `9` mean? A Google search for `perl` interpreter's exit codes turned up nothing. Where can I find a list of exit codes for the Perl interpreter?

Comment: The perl binary is giving a return value but is it the binary or the application? That is, I can write a perl program with `exit(253)` in it and that will be the return value of the process.

Comment: exit values near 255 are often due to shells or other wrappers. Is 253 your shell telling you something like "couldn't find perl" or "out of resources, couldn't fork"?

Comment: So it turns out code 253 is due to the program not finding the filepath. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [perldoc perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html):

> If the program is syntactically correct, it is executed. If the program runs off the end without hitting an `exit()` or `die()` operator, an implicit `exit(0)` is provided to indicate successful completion.

Thus, the program you are running must be somehow specifying those exit values via [die](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html), [exit](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exit.html) or equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

The perl interpreter actually *does* return exit codes of its own if the script doesn't run. Most syntax errors lead to exit code 9:

Unknown function / disallowed bareword:

```
perl -e 'use strict; print scalar(localtime); schei;'
```

$? = 9

division by zero:

```
perl -e 'use strict; print scalar(localtime); my $s = 1/0;'
```

$? = 9

syntax error:

```
perl -e 'use strict; print scalar(localtime); my $ff; $ff(5;'
```

$? = 9

using die:

```
perl -e 'use strict; print scalar(localtime); die "twaeng!"'
```

$? = 9

an unknown module was the only one situation I found perl to exit differently:

```
perl -e 'use strict; use doof; print scalar(localtime);'
```

$? = 2

BTW I'm still searching for a comprehensive list of the perl interpreter's exit codes myself. Anyone got an idea where to look, aside from the perl interpreters sources?

Comment: the perldoc for [`die`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) has some information about the exit code, but suggests that you not rely on the exit code other than its being non-zero

Comment: I think that this is the most comprehensive answer. Thank you, @elwood

Answer (score 4):

In normal circumstances, `perl` will return whatever the program it runs returns. Hence you can not generalize the meaning of the return value without knowing the program it's running.

Answer (score 3):

Perl itself doesn't have any defined exit codes; unless the perl interpreter crashes in a really horrific way, the exit code is determined by the program that `perl` is running, not by `perl` itself.

Comment: I read that I had to bitshift the return value right 8bits to get the script's return value? Don't they output their return values side by side, occupying one byte each?

Answer (score 1):

Since the error code changed after some runs; if you are running a `Java` app as a continuously running webapp, check if it can be some kind of memory leak.

You can test your `perl` script from various problems by running it with the perl interpreter's `-Tw` options, for tainted modes and warnings enabled, see [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for more info about these.

Comment: Can you explain why taint would help totrck this problem down?